# Ember.js - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebarshelper

I can't seem to correct the error in the console. My code searches the text files for a query term. If the query term is present, I want the query term in the text to be highlighted. Not able to figure out this.

```
  var App = Ember.Application.create();   
    App.Router.map(function() {
      // index route is created by default
    });

    App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
        actions: {
            doSearch: function() {
                var self = this;
                self.set('results', null);
                Em.$.get('/patients/search?query='+this.get('searchText')).then(function(data) {
                    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                        var docs = data[i].documents;
                        var newDocs = [];
                        for (var j=0;j<docs.length;j++) {
                            parts = docs[j].split(":::");
                            newDocs.push({
                                title: parts[0],
                                date: parts[1],
                                contents: parts[2]
                            });
                        }
                        data[i].documents = newDocs;
                    }
                    self.set('results', data);
                });     
            }
        },

                var queryTerm = this.get('searchText');      //ERROR IN THIS LINE
                Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlightSearchTerm', function (text, queryTerm) {
                    var highlightedText = text.replace(new RegExp(queryTerm, 'gi'), function (str) {
                    return '<mark>' + str + '</mark>';
                });
            return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(highlightedText);
            });  
    });
```

Comment: You're getting an error because that line is outside the body of anything.

Comment: @alizahid Where should the whole function be placed? Can you please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `helper` should be its own piece of code.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Router.map(function() {
  // index route is created by default
})

App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    doSearch: function() {
      var self = this

      self.set('results', null)

      Em.$.get('/patients/search?query=' + this.get('searchText')).then(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var docs = data[i].documents

          var newDocs = []

          for (var j = 0; j < docs.length; j++) {
            parts = docs[j].split(':::')

            newDocs.push({title: parts[0], date: parts[1], contents: parts[2]})
          }

          data[i].documents = newDocs
        }

        self.set('results', data)
      })
    }
  }
})

Ember.Handlebars.helper('highlightSearchTerm', function(text, queryTerm) {
  var highlightedText = text.replace(new RegExp(queryTerm, 'gi'), function(str) {
    return '<mark>' + str + '</mark>'
  })

  return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(highlightedText)
})
```

And then you use the helper in your template like

```
{{highlightSearchTerm searchText}}
```

Comment: Also, I don't know how old this app you're working on is, but you can clean that code up a LOT.

Comment: I get the error "Ember.Handlebars.helper is not a function" when I ran the app. I also tried  `Ember.Helper.helper(function(params) {});`  - as I read that in version 2 they removed all Ember.Handlebars interface calls. But even after this change I still get `Compile Error: highlightSearchTerm is not a helper`. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: This is my front-end code `<div class="container">
        <h2><mark>{{patient.name}}</mark></h2>
        {{#each patient.documents as |document|}}
        <br>
        <div class="content">
            <pre><div>{{document.title}}</div>                                            
                 <div>{{document.date}}</div>
                 {{highlightSearchTerm document.contents}}</pre>    
                                                    
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        {{/each}}
        <hr>
    </div>`